# Need to plot boundary of a city and nearby cities in google map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I am now developing a site which supports tourism in Japan using Ruby on Rails. For that I want to show user's selected city in a map with nearby cities in different border color. I have downloaded a kml file from the [site](http://www.gadm.org/download) having the co-ordinate informations of all cities in japan. Now, I need get nearby cities of a selected cities and also the co-ordinate of the cities. I am thinking of two options

1. To save each cities in separate file and fetching data from the files.
2. Save it in a seperate table with co-oridnates as text field

Can you suggest which one is good. Is there any better option.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be better to create a table for the City model, and use it to store whatever relevant information you need from the kml file (such as the coordinates).
Since this data is not going to change in the near future, you can use the file to seed those tables once and then work directly with the cities registries.